# Django form doesn't work properly, error is always != 0

Tags: javascript, django, forms, checkout

I am building a payment/checkout form in Django. If the user doesn't fill in the info during checkout, they will get stuck there until they fill in everything.

I suppose that the problem is that the error is constantly != 0. However, it cannot be.

Here is the code that I have problem with:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form')

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
})

document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    const form = document.getElementById('form')

    let error = formValidate(form);

    if (error != 0) {
        alert('smth typed in')
    }
    else {
        submitFormData()
    }
})

function formValidate(form) {
    var error = 0;
    let formReq = document.querySelectorAll('._req');

    for (let index = 0; index < formReq.length; index++) {
        const input = formReq[index]
        formRemoveError(input);

        if (input.classList.contains('_email')) {
            if (emailTest(input)) {
                formAddError(input);
                error++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (input.value === '') {
                formAddError(input);
                error++;
            }
        }

    }
}
function formAddError(input) {
    input.parentElement.classList.add('_error')
    input.classList.add('_error');
}
function formRemoveError(input) {
    input.parentElement.classList.remove('_error')
    input.classList.remove('_error');
}
function emailTest(input) {
    return !/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/.test(input.value);
}
```

Comment: can you share the error ?

Comment: There is no error either in teminal or in console, bu if you mean the ._error, it just changes the color of the form